# C# Calling datalist selected items in form1 to form2

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datalist in form1. How I can bring the selected datalist items to form2?

That is code in form1. When I click to context menu form2 comes. I want to bind selected items's common datas in a table to a datagrid in form2.

```
 protected void showKontextMenu(string key, int col = -1, WlistRow row = null)
    {
          int cou = datalist.SelectedItems.Count;
             if (utilDB.isAllowed(utilDB.eDBRights.eEditor) && cou>1)
            {
                cm.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Header = utilText.sstr("Stichworte und Attribute"), Name = "AttrEdit", Tag = key });
            }
        cm.AddHandler(MenuItem.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(KontextMenu_Click));
        cm.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Dejo also, there are many ways. But I guess the simplest and most effective way is following.

- Create static variables in the main program.
- Assign values to those variables from from1.
- Access them from form2.

Hope you get it (without the sample code!)

Answer (score 0):

save selected value in some variable in form1 & access that variable from form2

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways.

Common are to save data to a for example object, and access it from another class (form)

You can also make constructor with type datalist as a parameter and send your data with constructor call.

Comment: Could you make a simple example??

Answer (score 0):

You could expose a Property on your Form1 and access it from Form2

Add a property on your Form1

```
private DataList _formOneList
public DataList FormOneList
{
    get{return _formOneList;}
}
```

Access it on your Form2

```
private DataList FormTwoList
Form2.FormTwoList=Form1.FormOneList;
```